# Null Pointer when adding checkbox to ArrayList Android?

Tags: java, android, checkbox, arraylist

My program is crashing when I add a `CheckBox` to my `ArrayList`. I can't see where or how I'm not declaring the `CheckBox`. Any help is appreciated.

```
public class Para_First_Fragment extends Fragment {
    View view;      

    ArrayList<CheckBox> ethChecks;      
    CheckBox cb_white, cb_black, cb_asian, cb_native, cb_other;     

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.para_first_fragment, container, false);            

        cb_white = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.fpc_white_cb);
        cb_black = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.fpc_black_cb);
        cb_asian = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.fpc_asian_cb);
        cb_native = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.fpc_natives_cb);
        cb_other = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.fpc_other_cb);

        ethChecks.add(cb_white); <-- Line 43
        ethChecks.add(cb_black);
        ethChecks.add(cb_asian);
        ethChecks.add(cb_native);
        ethChecks.add(cb_other);            

        return view;
    }

}
```

When the fragment loads it crashes and my logcat gives me the following error

```
11-24 14:54:36.961: E/AndroidRuntime(3399): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-24 14:54:36.961: E/AndroidRuntime(3399):     at com.example.myproject.Para_First_Fragment.onCreateView(Para_First_Fragment.java:43)
```

Line 43 is commented in the code above. Now the `CheckBox` isn't "checked" but I can't imagine that matters at all. I have a feeling I'm declaring or adding it before/after I'm supposed to. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Look at line 43 in your `Para_First_Fragment` class.

Comment: Well, you didn't really initialize the list.

Comment: Yea, I need some air. This was way too silly of an error to miss. Upside someone gets some rep, downside I will undoubtedly get downvotes and I have further contributed to the excess of 100000 of the same question... =(

Comment: The real lesson here is that you shouldn't debug through stackoverflow. And for this particular case it's just: _Something's null. Is it initialized? No. Done._ I realise that people that are new to programming won't realise this, but they can do the research.

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ yep, first time I've ever voted to close my own question. That should say something in itself.

Comment: I'll add that I've done this myself :) Lesson learned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never assigned an `ArrayList` to ethChecks, so it's still null!

Either initialize it directly where the field is declared:

```
List<CheckBox> ethChecks = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
```

or insert the following line somewhere before dereferencing `ethChecks`:

```
ethChecks = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
```

Comment: just kill me... *facepalm*. Answer will be accepted in 10 mins when the timers up. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You also have to initialise the ArrayList

```
ArrayList<CheckBox> ethChecks = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
```

Comment: thanks, +1 for taking the time to answer such a silly question. Time for some air, I should not of missed that